# Potential problems with object literal and object constructor in one array?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, polymorphism, literals

I want to deeply understand object creation in JavaScript. Generally, I understand the differences between creation methods, etc. Can you describe the difference and influence on working with the object array in these two cases, when I have objects in the array created using two ways below?

```js
function Animal(name, species) {
  this.name = name,
  this.species = species
}

var animals = [
  {name: 'azor', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'mruczek', species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'burek', species: 'dog'},
];

//Case 1
newAnimal = {name: 'motek', species: 'buterfly'}
animals.push(newAnimal);
console.log(animals);

console.log('---');

//Case 2
newAnimal = new Animal('bongo', 'elephant');
animals.push(newAnimal);
console.log(animals);
```

I ask because if I use the `console` it will show

```
[ { name: 'azor', species: 'dog' },
  { name: 'mruczek', species: 'cat' },
  { name: 'burek', species: 'dog' },
  { name: 'motek', species: 'buterfly' } ]
---
[ { name: 'azor', species: 'dog' },
  { name: 'mruczek', species: 'cat' },
  { name: 'burek', species: 'dog' },
  { name: 'motek', species: 'buterfly' },
  Animal { name: 'bongo', species: 'elephant' } ]
```

#### Question

Is it a problem to have objects created using a literal and constructor in same array like in `//Case 2`?

Comment: An array can hold objects and primitives of any type. The display of the console is not standardized. Are you _actually_ experiencing any problems currently?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it fundamentally, but if `Animal` has any methods on the `prototype`, none of the object literals will have those methods.

Comment: So If I want to work with with map(), filter() etc. there will not be difference/problems? Currently I have no problems with It. No I have not methods, just the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the objects to truly be an `instanceof Animal`, you can use [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to redefine the objects' `prototype`:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor (name, species) {
    this.name = name;
    this.species = species;
  }

  greet () {
    return `My name is ${this.name} and I am a ${this.species}`;
  }
}

var animals = [
  {name: 'azor', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'mruczek', species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'burek', species: 'dog'},
];

animals.push({name: 'motek', species: 'buterfly'});
animals.push(new Animal('bongo', 'elephant'));

animals.forEach(animal => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(animal, Animal.prototype)
});

console.log(`Are all the animals actually an Animal? ${
  animals.every(animal => animal instanceof Animal)
}`);
console.log(animals.map(animal => animal.greet()));
```

Or you can use a form of polymorphism to treat all the objects like an `Animal` by using [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```js
class Animal {
  constructor (name, species) {
    this.name = name;
    this.species = species;
  }

  greet () {
    return `My name is ${this.name} and I am a ${this.species}`;
  }
}

var animals = [
  {name: 'azor', species: 'dog'},
  {name: 'mruczek', species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'burek', species: 'dog'},
];

animals.push({name: 'motek', species: 'buterfly'});
animals.push(new Animal('bongo', 'elephant'));

// animals.forEach(animal => {
//   Object.setPrototypeOf(animal, Animal.prototype)
// });

console.log(`Are all the animals actually an Animal? ${
  animals.every(animal => animal instanceof Animal)
}`);
console.log(animals.map(animal => Animal.prototype.greet.call(animal)));
```

Note that in this case they are still as they were originally defined but you can call `prototype` methods of `Animal` and pass each instance as the calling context.

Oh, and the reason the `console.log()` output is different is because the [`[Symbol.toStringTag]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) property, which you can overload:

```
var newAnimal = {name: 'motek', species: 'buterfly', [Symbol.toStringTag]: 'Animal'}
console.log(newAnimal);
// Animal {name: "motek", species: "buterfly", Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Animal"}
```

Comment: Ok, but what If I want to use a object constructor to add a object to array (shorter syntax) but In console the object should looks like a literal object (for consistency). Is it good/possible at all?

Comment: @NetPax Just use a function that returns an object (literal). No need for a constructor.